# How can I determine whether a user is an tenant admin using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I used GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf with a tenant admin and received the following object in the response:

```
    {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole",
        "id": "f68149ec-f518-4905-92d3-cc27f82f54c3",
        "deletedDateTime": null,
        "description": "Company Administrator role has full access to perform any operation in the company scope.",
        "displayName": "Company Administrator",
        "roleTemplateId": "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10"
    }
```

Can I use the `roleTemplateId` property where the value equals `62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10` to determine whether the user is a tenant admin?

**Update after initial answers**
This will only work for admins that have [directory permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#directory-permissions) which are only available for admins. This won't work for a non-admin users. I was unclear in my original question.

Comment: Of course, the `roleTemplateId` is static, you could use this powershell command `Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleTemplate | ? { $_.DisplayName -eq "Company Administrator" }` to find it.

Comment: Does the roleTemplateId change for each tenant? or its static over all tenants.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use the roleTemplateId property where the value equals
>   62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10 to determine whether the user is
>   a tenant admin?

For your response, the company administrator means tenant administrator. If you want to use `roleTemplateId-value` to check, you can use GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoleTemplates/{roleTemplatedID-value}", and the response like this:
[image]

In the response, the company administrator means the global administrator.

And as I know, in the single tenant, the company administrator is the tenant administrator.

Comment: is there a way for an app to determine whether a user is an admin without having Directory scopes? roleTemplateId via memberOf is only available with the Directory scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test result, you can use the roleTemplateId property where the value equals 62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10 to determine whether the user is a tenant admin now. But because there is no official document to state this, so it's not stable,you need to regularly check the update of official documents.